# Converting text strings to numbers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am working in QGIS, which is quite new to me.

I have a text string containing dates.

I want to have new column where only the year from the text-date string appears. How is that possible. See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the field calculator.

You would first extract the 4 rightmost characters, then convert them to an integer:

```
to_int(right(dato,4))
```

Comment: Won't they need single quotation marks around the field name, like this `'dato'`? Otherwise I think it will just try to convert the word `dato` to an integer, and deliver a `NULL` result.

Comment: @csk no, with single quotes it would be the string `'dato'`, not the field name. It works without any quotes or with double quotes

Comment: Hm. Field names working without quotes must be a new feature in QGIS3.

Comment: @csk I just tried it in 2.18 and it works too (open a shapefile/temp layer, calculator, new field, expression is right( fieldname ,2) and it does preview + populate).

Comment: Interesting. I learned by using the built-in help in the Expression Builder, which puts field names in double quotation marks. Perhaps that's necessary when the field name has spaces, or matches another variable or function. I will have to pay attention to this in the future.

Comment: @csk indeed the [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#fields-and-values) changed from "field should be double-quoted" to "type the field name (preferably inside double quotes)"

Comment: have a read of this post as well. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402362/extracting-numbers-from-text-attribute-in-qgis