# Extracting numbers from text attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, integer

Is it possible to make a new column and store only the numbers in the column `"GNR"` i.e. removing `(1:  ))`?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a proper *regexp* term using the [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#regexp-substr) function:

```
 to_int( regexp_substr( "GNR", ':([^)]+)\)' ) )
```

that retrieves all characters between `:` & `)` like so:

- `:`: match sequence must start with this character
- `(`: start retrieving sub-string
- `[^)]+`: collect all characters that are not `)`
- `)`: end retrieving sub-string
- `\)`: match sequence must end with this character (escaped because `)` is a meta character)

Answer (score 6):

Use one of these expressions:

`replace (replace (GNR, '(1:',''),')','')`

`left (substr( GNR,4),length('GNR')-1)`